# ngFor and (click) not working in Ionic 2 & Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2, click, ngfor

When iterating through an array of items for ngFor, the (click) event is failing to attach to each list item, for some reason it just doesn't attach and when I click on each of the list items, the function is not triggered.

Here is the HTML for the list:

```
<ion-list class="queue-page--actions__haircut__tab-open" radio-group *ngIf="haircutTab" [(ngModel)]="selectedCut">
    <ion-list-header class="queue-page--actions__haircut__tab__header">
      Select a cut
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of getCuts()" (click)="open($event, item)">
      <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>£{{item.price}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio checked="{{item.name == selectedCut}}" value="{{item.name}}"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Get cuts is the function on the controller for the page (this.cuts is of type array and returns an array of json objects):

```
public getCuts(){
    return this.cuts;
}
```

And finally, the open() function is as follows:

```
public open(event, item){
    alert("Clicked");
    console.log(item)
}
```

Can't figure out what's going wrong here, perhaps a suspicion of scope issues but really not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of cuts" (click)="open(item)">
:
</ion-item>
```

Comment: This is how I originally coded it, however this did not work. No idea why, as i've used this same format in other formats. My guess is that when you click an Ionic radio button, the click event is being stopped for some reason. I have posted a solution that I found for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-how-to-handle-change-event-radio-button/71556) on the Ionic 2 forum I have found a solution to the problem presented here.

Instead of using `(click)`, I am now using `(ionSelect)` on the `ion-radio` element. An example can be seen here:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of cuts" (click)="open(item)">
      <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>£{{item.price}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio (ionSelect)="cutChanged(item.name)" checked="{{item.name == selectedCut}}" value="{{item.name}}"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

Where the function on the controller for **cutChanged()** is like so:

```
cutChanged(cut){
    alert(cut);
}
```

This implementation now works and fires on click events. Perhaps something unusual with how radio buttons work in Ionic?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with angular 8, Any idea how to get it resolved in Angular 8?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getCuts()` method is not required.
No need to pass the event when the `open()` function is called. Also there is a semicolon missing in your `open()` method. Final Code :

```
<ion-list class="queue-page--actions__haircut__tab-open" radio-group *ngIf="haircutTab" [(ngModel)]="selectedCut">
    <ion-list-header class="queue-page--actions__haircut__tab__header">
      Select a cut
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of cuts" (click)="open(item)">
      <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-label>£{{item.price}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio checked="{{item.name == selectedCut}}" value="{{item.name}}"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

open() function will be :

```
public open(event, item){
    alert("Clicked");
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: I originally had it as cuts instead of getCuts(). I implemented the getCuts() as a suggestion from another StackOverflow Q. The above implementation that you suggested unfortunately do not work either, no event is fired with the ionic radio buttons are clicked on.